Unable to import h5py in anaconda jupyter on windows 10
I want to save  tensorflow model using Jupyter on Windows 10. I get import error that h5py must be installed to save the model. I installed the latest version of h5py. I have tried saving the model as model.h5 and model.keras but import error that h5py must be installed remains. I have looked at similar problems reported in stackoverflow in the past but was not able to find a solution.
I have updated anaconda,

h5py version: 3.11.0.
Python version: 3.11.5.
Cython version: 3.0.10.
Tensorflow version: 2.17.0.

Where am I going wrong and what changes  can I make?
Error when saving model as model.save('model.keras'):
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[93], line 1
----> 1 model.save('model.keras')

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\saving\saving_lib.py:63, in save_model(model, filepath, weights_format)
     39 """Save a zip-archive representing a Keras model to the given file or path.
     40 
     41 The zip-based archive contains the following structure:
   (...)
     60 layer attribute.
     61 """
     62 if weights_format == "h5" and h5py is None:
---> 63     raise ImportError("h5py must be installed in order to save a model.")
     65 if not model.built:
     66     warnings.warn(
     67         "You are saving a model that has not yet been built. "
     68         "It might not contain any weights yet. "
   (...)
     71         stacklevel=2,
     72     )

ImportError: h5py must be installed in order to save a model.

Error when saving model with h5 extension: model.save('model.h5):
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[91], line 1
----> 1 model.save('model.h5')

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\legacy_h5_format.py:28, in save_model_to_hdf5(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
     26 def save_model_to_hdf5(model, filepath, overwrite=True, include_optimizer=True):
     27     if h5py is None:
---> 28         raise ImportError(
     29             "`save_model()` using h5 format requires h5py. Could not "
     30             "import h5py."
     31         )
     33     if not isinstance(filepath, h5py.File):
     34         # If file exists and should not be overwritten.
     35         if not overwrite and os.path.isfile(filepath):

ImportError: `save_model()` using h5 format requires h5py. Could not import h5py.

Error when importing h5py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[78], line 1
----> 1 import h5py

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:25
     19 # --- Library setup -----------------------------------------------------------
     20 
     21 # When importing from the root of the unpacked tarball or git checkout,
     22 # Python sees the "h5py" source directory and tries to load it, which fails.
     23 # We tried working around this by using "package_dir" but that breaks Cython.
     24 try:
---> 25     from . import _errors
     26 except ImportError:
     27     import os.path as _op

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _errors: The specified procedure could not be found.


"I installed the latest version of h5py." How and where? Just installing it somewhere on your machine isn't going to help as Jupyter is very particular about having it installed where the kernel environment is. On top of this, you mention Anaconda in your post. That has ways to keep things very isolated. You have to follow its environment management practices very strictly for things to work. Did you read and follow the Anaconda getting started information and information about managing environments?

You can make a new cell and try running %conda install conda-forge::h5py in the running Jupyter .ipynb file. (Based on here and the use of the magic install command for running inside an active Jupyter .ipynb file.) Then if it runs successfully, restart the kernel and try the import statement.

Initially, I installed h5py in Jupyter using pip install h5py.  I tried your suggestion %conda install conda-forge::h5py . After this import h5py still failed

If you are using Anaconda/conda, then you should be using conda for everything and only resort to pip for things that don't have a conda recipe. This is what it means to choose that as your primary package manager. As for the part, "After this import h5py still failed": After what? Did it successfully install or tell you something? If the import failed after that, I'm guessing it didn't install and you are leaving out that detail. Or maybe you didn't restart things and try?  Do you see it listed when you run %conda list in a new cell in the notebook where you want to import it?

the message I got after installing conda forge h5py is big and will not fit here.  But this part of output seems to be what's causing the problem: Error while loading conda entry point: anaconda-cloud-auth (cannot import name 'ChannelAuthBase' from 'conda.plugins.types' (C:\Users\sraza\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\types.py))
Error while loading conda entry point: anaconda-cloud-auth (cannot import name 'ChannelAuthBase' from 'conda.plugins.types' (C:\Users\sraza\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\types.py))

also this: The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

defaults/win-64::bcrypt==3.2.0=py311h2bbff1b_1
defaults/noarch::paramiko==2.8.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
defaults/win-64::scrapy==2.8.0=py311haa95532_0
defaults/win-64::spyder==5.4.3=py311haa95532_1
defaults/win-64::twisted==22.10.0=py311h2bbff1b_0
defaults/win-64::_anaconda_depends==2023.09=py311_mkl_1


Also just wanted to let you know I did try to use %conda install h5py and it did not work. After this I tried pip install of h5py. I did start kernel before trying to import h5py.

I dont know if I made the right choice  but I just did conda update  --all. to prevent package inconsistencies  everyting seemed to installl ok except for this: Error while loading conda entry point: anaconda-cloud-auth (cannot import name 'ChannelAuthBase' from 'conda.plugins.types' (C:\Users\sraza\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\types.py))
Error while loading conda entry point: anaconda-cloud-auth (cannot import name 'ChannelAuthBase' from 'conda.plugins.types' (C:\Users\sraza\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\types.py))

restarted kernel and did import of h5py and still failed. Thank you for your patience and taking the time to provide feedback

Don't just restart kernel. It is best when restarting the kernel to restart everything, including Jupyter, browser, and the entire machine. Restarting the kernel is usualy enough when things seem okay, but you are troubleshooting. That stuff that failed looked like cloud stuff, but did it mess up the rest of that command or did it run otherwise? Also if you are new to this, then just uninstalling the Anaconda Distribution and reinstalling the latest is best at this point instead of conda update --all. You'd move to the updating when you have environments you know work and want to make...

 new ones and then you'd run that in the new environments you make to get started with newer stuff without messing up your other projects or base environment. The whole point of Ancaconda/conda to make environments for projects and not touch your base stuff. At this point though I don't know what to advise for installing h5py. I'd research people posting about installing it on Windows 10 and see what they advise.

Thank you so much for your help and feedback. I will reinstall anaconda although I feel I didn't really make any significant changes to the environment other than updating anaconda prior to having the issues with h5py.  I will try to do an installation of an older version of conda first and see if h5py works.  Thanks again

I wasn't really suggesting that in this case. Just trying to say I didn't see the point for running conda update --all here since everything worked with the exception of this package. Since it doesn't come as part of Anaconda/conda, it won't help to install a newer version of the Anaconda Distribution. One thing to consider though is that h5py may be easier to install in WSL than your main Windows system, see here. That would be the place to install the fresh Anaconda Distribution.
